# Vector drawable not scaling

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, drawable, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to set my linearlayout background to a vector drawable, however it is not scaling to fill the entire layout, below is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ideaBody"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="229dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_greenbackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">
```

and the following is my vector xml;:

```
<vector android:height="500dp" android:viewportHeight="297.0"
    android:viewportWidth="210.0" android:width="500dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.42" android:fillColor="#008000"
        android:pathData="M1.14,40.02h58.21v60.59h-58.21z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.76" android:strokeWidth="0.26458332"/>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this if you want to set green background to your layout.

Change your XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#73008000" />
        <stroke android:width="0.76dp" android:color="#BF008000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: I have a whole range of complex vector assets id like to import from inkscape so this solution is not appropriate, thanks